# Как добавить столбец с данными в CSV файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Нужно добавить в CSV файл столбец c результатами парсинга:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\Arcgis\TATARS2.CSV',delimiter=';')

for da in df.address:
    r = requests.get('http://search.maps.sputnik.ru/search/addr?q='+da)
    data = (r.json()['result']['address'][0]['features'][0]['geometry']['geometries'][0]['coordinates'])
    frame = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[da]) 
    frame.to_csv(r'D:\Arcgis\TATARS2.CSV',index=False)
```

Как это правильно прописать?

На данный момент, файл просто перезаписывается, причем все данные пишутся в один столбец.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы добавить один столбец в DataFrame можно воспользоваться одним из следующих методов:

- df[“new_column”] = <list / series / numpy vector>
- df.assign
- df.join
- df.insert

Чтобы добавить сразу несколько столбцов можно воспользоваться:

- df.merge
- df[[“col1”, “col2”]] = ...

Для того чтобы получить более развёрнутый ответ приведите в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример данных и результат, который вы хотите получить.

Answer (score 1):

Какие столбцы? Куда добавлять? Ничего не понятно. Но запись в csv-файл действительно можно выполнить с помощью метода to_csv. Аналогично, чтение из csv-файла -  с помощью метода read_csv. Соответственно  ответ на ваш вопрос - с учетом стиля и формы его формулировки - следующий:

> 1. Читаем csv-файл в DataFrame.
> 2. Добавляем DataFrame необходимыми столбцами.
> 3. Записывает DataFrame в csv-файл.

Если необходимо более конкретный ответ -  потрудитесь сформулировать свой вопрос более конкретно.